# C++ unexecuted code changes function behaviour?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I use the following code (taken from https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/22901/reading-all-bytes-from-a-file) to efficiently read a file into an array in C++:

```
static std::vector<char> ReadAllBytes(char const* filename)
{
    std::ifstream ifs(filename, std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
    std::ifstream::pos_type pos = ifs.tellg();

    std::vector<char> result(pos);

    ifs.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    ifs.read(&result[0], pos);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++)
        if (result.at(i) != 0)
            return result; // [1]

    //if (!ifs.good()) // Commenting out changes contents of result
    //    return result; // [2] // Commenting out changes contents of result

    return result; // [3]
}
```

Everything works perfectly, a breakpoint at [1] fires and the function returns the data (the loop is just for debug, as I have been getting 0-filled returns which should hold data). However, as soon as I remove the If-Statement at [2], breakpoint [3] fires and the array is empty (the size is correct, but the array is filled with zeros).

How can code which is never executed actually change the behavior of the function? I figured it might have something to do with the stack layout and the fact that I hold the stream and the data as local variables but manually creating them on the heap leads to the exact same situation.

You see me completely baffled. I have never seen something quite like this before. How can this be possible?

PS: I should add that the file contents are binary and the file is about ~32 MB in size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wondering: I could not pinpoint the reason for the strange behavior of the C++-Compiler here (maybe I did indeed find a bug?).

However, as soon as the file is read in chunks, everything works flawlessly. I'll post the code for your convenience:

```
static bool ReadAllBytes(char const* filename, char** result, size_t* size)
{
    const size_t BUFFER_SIZE = 32;  
    std::ifstream ifs(filename, std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate | std::ios::in);

    *size = ifs.tellg();
    *result = new char[*size];
    ifs.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

    size_t operations = *size / BUFFER_SIZE;
    size_t chunks = 0;
    for (; chunks < operations && ifs.good(); chunks++)
        ifs.read(*result + chunks * BUFFER_SIZE, BUFFER_SIZE);

    if (ifs.good() && *size % BUFFER_SIZE > 0)
        ifs.read(*result + chunks * BUFFER_SIZE, *size % BUFFER_SIZE);

    return (ifs.good());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you compiling with optimizations (release mode)? If so, then if I had to guess, I would say it's reordering your code. First off, notice that none of the code after the `read` actually matters. All it's doing is returning `result` in all cases and not changing anything in the array. Many of the functions could be inlined which means a good compiler could know this and remove all that code.

So that could easily explain the breakpoint behavior. But adding the `if (!ifs.good())` and having the data be empty - that's tough to explain. Perhaps this tidbit about the `read` function provides insight:

> Internally, the function accesses the input sequence by first constructing a sentry object (with noskipws set to true). Then (if good), it extracts characters from its associated stream buffer object as if calling its member functions sbumpc or sgetc, and finally destroys the sentry object before returning.

Notice that read contains a check on `good()`, which means that perhaps the compiler is combining the two checks of `good()` (the one in the `read`, after inlining, and the one in your code) and using that to skip the read entirely(?). That seems really unlikely, but perhaps it points you in a direction to debug.

I will say that I've seen this problem before with the optimizer. Not this specific problem with ifstreams but the more general problem that adding seemingly unused code changes the behavior. And the reason always ends up being that it's free to reorder code that doesn't change the results.

Comment: I'm on VS 2012, Debug-Mode (x64, /Od Optimization disabled) - the compiler shouldn't optimize anything (thanks for your answer though)! I will look into the Read-Behavior but it still seems very odd to me that the check for good() actually changes data. That still does not seem right to me (especially with optimizations off).

Comment: I would try a ifs.gcount() after the read, and checking its value vs pos.